# How to open a local file from your USB

Tags: html

I was creating some games to show others and I came across this problem. I was using a USB to store my web pages in .html and I wanted an html page to open up and replace the current page. For example, I want `html1.html` to be able to open up `html2.html`. I've searched up answers although they use the C drive. Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: Please provide more detail. Why not use relative links?

Comment: What do you mean by relative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a link like so:

```
<a href="html2.html">Go to page 2</a>
```

This link will work as long as html2.html is in the same folder as the initial html file.

If you want to redirect automatically, you can use a meta tag. The samble below will redirect to html2.html after 3 seconds.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=html2.html">
```

Comment: OK im a noob should've thought about that. I though about something more difficult xD